# Execute Datastage Data Flow Designer REST API

Tags: rest, datastage

I'm trying to use the REST API function to compile a job. Following is the syntax used.URL was executed directly in a browser and gave user and password when the pop-up asked for it.

```
https://<serv:port>/ibm/iis/api/dscdesignerapi?api=compileDSJob&jobName=<job name>&projectName=<Project>&hostName=<engine>&getFullOutput=true&apiVersion=LATEST
```

I got the following error message. Can someone guide what is wrong here.

```
{"restApiName":"doPost: compileDSJob","failureMessage":[{"errorMessage":"com.ibm.iis.xmeta.client.exception.usage.InvalidParameterException: Null RID"}],"succeeded":false,"errorDetails":{"method":"compileDSJob","messageEnglish":"com.ibm.iis.xmeta.client.exception.usage.InvalidParameterException: Null RID","message":"com.ibm.iis.xmeta.client.exception.usage.InvalidParameterException: Null RID","class":"DSJsonApiServlet"}}
```

Comment: Hi,
Are you able to resolve the issue, we are also facing the same issue even though we are providing proper authentication.
It was working earlier, suddenly we are getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Null RID, error because user did not login to the flow designer？